# c++11 lambda function with variable parameter list

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I did not find this question in SO. If it is a duplicate please refer to the answer and close this question.

Can a C++11 lambda function have a variable parameter list?

```
auto displayMessage = [objectLog] (const char * sFormat, ...) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11

Comment: @Overflowh, that doesn't seem to say anything about using `...` in a C++11 lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easier than I thought and as meant before nothing forbids it.

I must admit I could have tried it before but I am a C++ beginner and therefore I thought it is more complicated. Here is a code for a lambda function with variable parameter list. This lambda function is used for internal logging - either directly to stdout or to a file.

```
auto displayMessage = [objectLog] (const char * sFormatString, ...)
{
    char sMessage [MAX_LOG_LINE_LENGTH];
    va_list vArgPtr;
    va_start(vArgPtr, sFormatString);

    vsnprintf(sMessage, sizeof(sMessage), sFormatString, vArgPtr);
    // EDIT: according to Jonathan Wakely's comment - added va_end()...
    va_end(vArgPtr);

    if ( objectLog )
    {
        objectLog->insertLogEntry("%s", sMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s", sMessage);
    }
};
```

Comment: You're missing `va_end(vArgPtr)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the grammar allows it, and nothing forbids it.

A *lambda-declarator* is defined in 5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] as:

> *lambda-declarator*:
>       ( *parameter-declaration-clause* ) *mutable*<sub>opt</sub> *exception-specification*<sub>opt</sub> *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *trailing-return-type*<sub>opt</sub>

And a *parameter-declaration-clause* is defined in 8.3.5 [dcl.fct] as:

> *parameter-declaration-clause*:
>       *parameter-declaration-list*<sub>opt</sub> ...<sub>opt</sub>
>       *parameter-declaration-list* , ...

Also, G++, Clang and EDG all accept it without problems.

Under the hood, a C++11 lambda generates closure type with an `operator()` member function, and there is no reason that function can't have `...`, e.g. this lambda expression:

```
auto l = [](int, ...) { }
```

generates a type like this:

```
struct unnamed_closure_type {
  void operator()(int, ...) const { }
};
```

which is perfectly valid C++.

Comment: In fact, Clang won't allow you to use `va_start` in such lambda, it's a known bug (https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19617)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with `Apple LLVM 6` (`LLVM 3.5svn`) and it compiled just fine. 
I guess there's nothing very different from regular function calls here, with the only forbidden thing being the use of the `auto` keyword.